# MS Graph - 401 Unauthorized seemingly with proper token and access

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

I am working with an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application hosted on Azure and authenticates users through Microsoft using MSAL. I am getting the basic information through the authentication process like name, username and group claims. However, I want to access some additional information through MS Graph, like the users profile photo. Initial authentication and token acquisition runs smoothly, and sending a request to `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me` returns `200 OK`. When trying to call `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/photo/$value`, however, I get a `401 - Unauthorized` in return.

I have seen several other posts on this issue, but most of them concludes that the developer have either forgotten to ask for the proper consents, gotten tokens from the wrong endpoints, or similar issues. All of which I have confirmed not to be the case.

I have confirmed that the proper scopes are included in the token using https://jwt.ms/. I also tried asking for greater scopes than necessary. Currently I am using the following scopes: `openid profile User.ReadBasic.All User.Read.All User.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite.All`. According to the beta reference for [get user](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_get) the least required permission is `User.Read` and according to the reference for [get photo](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/profilephoto_get) the least required permission is also `User.Read`. Using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) I have also confirmed that I should have had access to the photo using the permissions that I do, although, I have not set any pictures on my profile so it gives me a `404` response.

I am at a loss as to why I cannot get access to the profile photo so any suggestions are much appreciated. If you need more information or details, please let me know. If relevant, I have a custom middleware that handles the post-authentication process of reading the user information which also makes the additional call to MS Graph for the photo.

### Edit:

I also tried `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{my-user-id}/photo/$value` which yielded the same results - 404 in Graph Explorer and 401 through my code

### Edit 2: Code

Here is the code that I am using. This first snippet is in a middleware that puts the claims from the authenticated user in a specific format. I have just been putting a break point on the return and inspected the response object.

```
public async Task GetUserPhotoAsync(string userid, HttpContext context)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var result = await new TokenHelper(_settings).GetAuthenticationAsync(userid, context, new string[] { "User.ReadBasic.All", "User.Read.All", "User.ReadWrite", "Files.ReadWrite.All" });
    var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/photo/$value";
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    return;
}
```

Here is the function that gets the token from the cache. `MSALSessionCache` is some code I have borrowed from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-v2) with some tweaks to fit .net core.

```
public async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetAuthenticationAsync(string signedInUserId, HttpContext context, string[] scopes)
{
    TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserId, context).GetMsalCacheInstance();


    ConfidentialClientApplication cca = 
        new ConfidentialClientApplication(_settings.ClientId, $"{_settings.Domain}/{_settings.AADInstance}/v2.0", "http://localhost:5000", new ClientCredential(_settings.ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);


    if (cca.Users.Count() > 0)
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes, cca.Users.First());
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

}
```

Initial token acquisition

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
    {
        string signedInUserId = context.Principal.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
        TokenCache userTokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(signedInUserId, context.HttpContext).GetMsalCacheInstance();

        ConfidentialClientApplication cca =
        new ConfidentialClientApplication(aadOptions.ClientId, aadOptions.RedirectUri, new ClientCredential(aadOptions.ClientSecret), userTokenCache, null);

        AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(context.ProtocolMessage.Code, new string[] { "User.ReadBasic.All", "User.Read.All", "User.ReadWrite", "Files.ReadWrite.All" });
        context.HandleCodeRedemption(result.AccessToken, result.IdToken);

    }
};
```

### Edit 3: Using the /v1.0 endpoint

As per Marc LaFleur's request I have tried the v1.0 endpoint with the same result. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me` gives a `200 OK` response code while `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value` returns `401 Unauthorized`

Comment: I've had problems with that endpoint on the v1 side too.. It seems like a bug or a mistake in the documentation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does this work with `/v1.0`? The 1.0 endpoint only retrieves photos from Exchange whereas the beta attempts to retrieve it from Exchange _or _AAD. Does this only happen for user's without a profile photo (asking so I can attempt to reproduce)?

Comment: It will be better that you could  add the reproduce demo code about how to get the bearer token.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I will try. I am not sure I have understood the differences here. Are the v1.0 endpoint the same as the old `graph.microsoft.net` endpoint, meaning that I need to use ADAL in stead of MSAL? I have registered the app in the app registration portal under `Converged applications`, does it need to be AAD Only app for v1.0?

Comment: @TomSun I can add some demo code, sure.

Comment: Please add the demo code. Then I will try to check it whether can be reproduced on my side or not.

Comment: @TomSun I have added some code. Is it enough?

Comment: @NiklasNoem  I will look into that. If need any other information, I will comment here.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I tried the 1.0 endpoint and updated my question accordingly :)

Comment: @NiklasNoem I also reproduce the issue with Microsoft graph explorer, I have sent mail to Microsoft team to get help. If there is any update, I will add the comment here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the Microsoft Graph giving a 401 Unauthorized exception when I was trying to query a user's photo or the photo's metadata on both the /V1.0 and /beta API endpoints. Like you, I verified I had the right tokens and was able to successfully access the user profile API.

In my case, I found it was because the photo for the user I was testing with hadn't been set. Once I assigned a photo I was able to successfully call both the photo value and photo metadata **beta** endpoints.

The v1.0 endpoints still gave me a 401 Unauthorized exception, but in my application I only use AzureAD, not Exchange. Based on @MarcLaFleur comments and the [API documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_get), this sounds like "expected" behaviour.

Why it returns a 401 Unauthorized instead of something like a 404 Not Found, or returning null values, I don't know.